Dificulty showing barchart values as annotation in Plotly
Because of the positioning I wanna use, it is not possible to achieve this using the built-in 'text' and 'textposition'. So I must create one annotation for each of them bars.
The real graph I'm trying to plot uses dates with a few gaps (a few years are missing from the chronological order) but for some odd reason I'm able to make it work when using string as index column. When using values (the real values I have) it does not properly work and I get weird gaps between the bars.
By checking my code and reading comments it'll be easier to understand what I mean:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

# Dummy Data for Global, China's, USA's, and India's Population (1970-2020)
years = [1975, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2020, 2040] #This is the right values I wanna use
# years = ['1975a', '1980a', '1990a', '2000a', '2020a', '2040a'] #Those values work cause adding 'a' prevents the script from turning those strs into int
global_population = [3.7, 4.4, 5.3, 6.1, 6.9, 7.8]  # In billions
china_population = [0.83, 0.98, 1.14, 1.26, 1.34, 1.41]  # In billions
usa_population = [0.205, 0.227, 0.249, 0.282, 0.309, 0.331]  # In billions (dummy values)
india_population = [0.554, 0.698, 0.873, 1.05, 1.21, 1.38]  # In billions (dummy values)

# Creating DataFrame
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': years,
    'Global Population (Billions)': global_population,
    'China Population (Billions)': china_population,
    'USA Population (Billions)': usa_population,
    'India Population (Billions)': india_population
})

# Function to add annotations with arrows
def add_annotations_with_arrows(fig, x_values, y_values, xshift=10, yshift=0.03, font_size=10, font_color="white", arrow_size=1):
    for i, x in enumerate(x_values):
        fig.add_annotation(
            x=str(x), #Forcing it to use as str to prevent errors
            y=y_values[i] + yshift,  # Position text slightly above each bar
            text=f"{y_values[i]:.2f}",  # Format text to 2 decimal places
            showarrow=True,  # Show the arrow
            arrowhead=0,  # Type of arrowhead
            arrowsize=arrow_size,  # Size of the arrow
            ax=0,  # X position of the arrow tip
            ay=-20,  # Y position of the arrow tip (controls how far the text is above the bar)
            font=dict(size=font_size, color=font_color),  # Set font size and color
            xshift=xshift,  # Shift the text slightly to the right
            align='center',  # Align text to the center
            arrowcolor=font_color  # Match arrow color to font color
        )

# Create the bar graph with Global, China, USA, and India's population
def create_bar_graph_with_usa_india(data, sig_val=2, title="Population Comparison (1970-2020)", x_label="Year", y_label="Population (Billions)"):
    fig = go.Figure()

    # Add bar for Global Population
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=data['Year'].astype(str),
        y=data['Global Population (Billions)'],
        name='Global Population',
        marker_color='blue',
        text=[f"{val:.2f}B" for val in data['Global Population (Billions)']],
        textposition='none'
    ))

    # Add bar for China's Population
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=data['Year'].astype(str),
        y=data['China Population (Billions)'],
        name="China's Population",
        marker_color='red',
        text=[f"{val:.2f}B" for val in data['China Population (Billions)']],
        textposition='none'
    ))

    # Add bar for USA's Population
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=data['Year'].astype(str),
        y=data['USA Population (Billions)'],
        name="USA's Population",
        marker_color='green',
        text=[f"{val:.2f}B" for val in data['USA Population (Billions)']],
        textposition='none'
    ))

    # Add bar for India's Population
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
        x=data['Year'].astype(str),
        y=data['India Population (Billions)'],
        name="India's Population",
        marker_color='orange',
        text=[f"{val:.2f}B" for val in data['India Population (Billions)']],
        textposition='none'
    ))

    # Adjust layout for better display
    fig.update_layout(
        barmode='group',  # Group bars for each year side by side
        title=title,
        xaxis=dict(title=x_label),
        yaxis=dict(title=y_label, range=[0, max(data['Global Population (Billions)']) * 1.1]),  # Adjust Y-axis
        plot_bgcolor='white',
        legend=dict(title="Population Type"),
        font=dict(size=12)
    )

    # Add annotations for Global Population
    add_annotations_with_arrows(
        fig, data['Year'], data['Global Population (Billions)'], xshift=-60, yshift=0.05, font_size=10, font_color="blue"
    )

    # Add annotations for China's Population
    add_annotations_with_arrows(
        fig, data['Year'], data['China Population (Billions)'], xshift=-10, yshift=0.05, font_size=10, font_color="red"
    )

    # Add annotations for USA's Population
    add_annotations_with_arrows(
        fig, data['Year'], data['USA Population (Billions)'], xshift=40, yshift=0.05, font_size=10, font_color="green"
    )

    # Add annotations for India's Population
    add_annotations_with_arrows(
        fig, data['Year'], data['India Population (Billions)'], xshift=100, yshift=0.05, font_size=10, font_color="orange"
    )

    return fig

# Generate the figure
fig = create_bar_graph_with_usa_india(data)

# Show the figure
fig.show()

This is the graph I get when using the data as "string + a" - this is the desired result
years = ['1975a', '1980a', '1990a', '2000a', '2020a', '2040a']


However, when using the real data (formatted as int) it completely loses formatting
years = [1975, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2020, 2040]


I'm aware that the annotations are messing up with formating because when I disable those blocks of code
# Add annotations for Global Population
add_annotations_with_arrows(
    fig, data['Year'], data['Global Population (Billions)'], xshift=-60, yshift=0.05, font_size=10, font_color="blue"
)

# Add annotations for China's Population
add_annotations_with_arrows(
    fig, data['Year'], data['China Population (Billions)'], xshift=-10, yshift=0.05, font_size=10, font_color="red"
)

# Add annotations for USA's Population
add_annotations_with_arrows(
    fig, data['Year'], data['USA Population (Billions)'], xshift=40, yshift=0.05, font_size=10, font_color="green"
)

# Add annotations for India's Population
add_annotations_with_arrows(
    fig, data['Year'], data['India Population (Billions)'], xshift=100, yshift=0.05, font_size=10, font_color="orange"
)

It works properly again even with the 'years' formatted as int.
I've tried forcing it to read as string but no success so any type of help would be much appreciated.
p.s: This is pseudocode I wrote in a very verbose way to try to identify and correct the problem. I'm sorry if it looks messy.

In order to treat years as integers and keep the desired behavior, you need to

Set the xaxis type to 'category' :
fig.update_layout(xaxis_type='category')


Place the annotations according to the underlying integer coordinate system, that is, use the category index instead of its label :
# Function to add annotations with arrows
def add_annotations_with_arrows(fig, x_values, ...):
  for i, x in enumerate(x_values):
      fig.add_annotation(x=i, ...)
# ...




Though you don't necessarily need annotations if you don't care about the arrows.
I suggest using plotly.express.bar() to do that the "express" way :
years = [1975, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2020, 2040]
global_population = [3.7e9, 4.4e9, 5.3e9, 6.1e9, 6.9e9, 7.8e9]
china_population = [0.83e9, 0.98e9, 1.14e9, 1.26e9, 1.34e9, 1.41e9]
usa_population = [0.205e9, 0.227e9, 0.249e9, 0.282e9, 0.309e9, 0.331e9]
india_population = [0.554e9, 0.698e9, 0.873e9, 1.05e9, 1.21e9, 1.38e9]

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Year': years,
    'Global Population (Billions)': global_population,
    'China Population (Billions)': china_population,
    'USA Population (Billions)': usa_population,
    'India Population (Billions)': india_population,
})

fig = px.bar(
    data,
    x='Year',
    y=data.columns[1:],
    barmode='group',
    text_auto=True, # Display formatted values on/above the bars
    title='Population Comparison (1970-2020)'
)

# Tweak how those values are displayed 
fig.update_traces(
    textfont_size=10,
    textangle=0,
    textposition='outside',
    cliponaxis=False
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis_type='category', # Would get gaps with 'linear' or 'date' axis
    yaxis_title='Population (Billions)',
    legend_title='Population Type',
)

fig.show()


Note :

Regarding the unit in your data, set 3.7e9 instead of 3.7 "billions" and let Plotly adjust the formatting automatically or, if necessary, tweak it using the dedicated properties (see below).
Setting text_auto to a d3-format formatting string will control the output format of the annotated values accordingly. If set to True, the formatting is determined by the tick settings of the corresponding axis (see exponentformat, tickformat, tickprefix, ticksuffix, etc.).
You can customize bar colors by setting color_discrete_sequence when calling px.bar.

See also :

px.bar()
Python Figure Reference: bar Traces
Bar Charts with Text


I appreciate your willingness to help me but for the amount of customization I need the 'express' way does not suffice. The arrows are not mandatory but certainly a nice addition. The 'real' graph I'm creating is quite complex so I must be able to pinpoint the exact placement for values or things will overlap. They can't be 'centered' or any of the premade options. This is way in my case displaying them as annotations would be optimal.

Ok, in general I avoid using annotations as much as possible because it's a bit tricky to obtain the right placement when the layout is supposed to be responsive (figure width/height not fixed), and especially when you have categorical axes, because you have to place the x/y using the corresponding axis coordinates, and tweak the x/y shifts in pixels, but it then depends on the client width/height and the actual range, so user interactions like zoom or resize window will make it wrong.

You can still use annotations and treat years as integers so you can customize the figure the way you want. See revised answer.

No one besides me will be using the code to generate them graphs so those 'user interactions' wont be a big issue. For me it is important to display them as annotations due to the amount of customization I need (so things don't overlap). I'll test the code again with the recommended changes and then I'll give feedback saying if I was able to make it work or not. Thanks!
